# Boostrap from-group style being crossed out

Tags: html

Im trying to reduce the vertical padding on the text form inputs. Specifically my html is:

```
<div class="form-group">

     <label...

     <input...
</div>
```

In my css, when I do the padding mod:

```
.form-group {   
    padding-bottom:1px;
}
```

it doesn't take (crossed in in the chrome dev tools)

However when i do

```
div.form-group{
    padding-bottom:1px;
}
```

it takes. Why is that?

Comment: You're more than likely dealing with a specificity issue. You can read more here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity.

PS I think your HTML snippet is missing.

Comment: similar issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047056/what-do-the-crossed-style-properties-in-google-chrome-devtools-mean/3047117#3047117