# Why CSS dimensions doesn't work on low width?

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, responsive, responsibility

i'm doing the responsibility of my page and i have a problem.
When i write for example this:

```
@media (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 580px) {
body {width: 100%; font-size: 15px;}}
```

dimensions dosen't work. I can't change any width, even font size. Only things like background-color work or margin-top/bottom, height...
Chrome shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdS9o.png),

The same things WORK in higher resolution.
I have in my code:

```
<meta charset ="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Check out this question. Your css is being overridden. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047056/what-do-the-crossed-style-properties-in-google-chrome-devtools-mean

Comment: man, it worked <3 thank you very much!! u made me so happy, seriously