# The .menu-item is not working in css for wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I just added my menus and that is working but they are the common blue with an underline.
So I wanted to give them another color etc.

You can do that with the .nav-item in css. But when i do that:

```
.menu-item{
  color: #fafafa;
}
```

It is not showing and the inspector shows this:

[image]

I have no idea what this means but I think the browser isn't reading this.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: There is another color property with higher specificity value which is overriding it. So try to increase the specificity of your selector by including parent elements. For example `nav .menu-item`

Comment: or you can force it with .menu-item{color: #fafafa !important}

Comment: _“I have no idea what this means”_ - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047056/what-do-the-crossed-style-properties-in-google-chrome-devtools-mean

Comment: @m4n0 thanks, but it isn't working. I checked and i think it is LI is overriding it but i have not LI in my style sheet

Comment: That `nav .menu-item` is just an example. I am not aware of what code you are using. If you can show me your webpage, I can give you the exact code needed.

Comment: @PeterJoe i did that and inspector sees it but it isn't applying to my menu

Comment: @m4n0 code or the actual page?

Comment: I'd prefer actual page.

Comment: @m4n0 i have found that A was overwriting it and when i give A a color it is working but that all my links are white

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer.
The .menu-item was being overrided by a

So i did this in my css:

```
.menu-item a{
color: #fafafa;
}
```

And now it works. Thanks to everyone who was trying to help!