# What does the light text mean in the chrome CSS debugger in the devtools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

A screenshot of a piece of the CSS debugger that comes up in the developer tools:

[image]

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047056/what-do-the-crossed-style-properties-in-google-chrome-devtools-mean) describes what the strikeout means: *"the crossed-out style was applied, but then overridden by a more specific selector, a more local rule, or by a later property within the same rule."*

What does the light text mean?  Where is there official documentation on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dimming indicates this property is not [inheritable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance) per CSS specification, i.e. it doesn't apply to the inspected element.

The dimmed declaration applies only to `body` in your screenshot.

Your screenshot says "Inherited from body" which means `body` is the ancestor of the inspected element and its non-dimmed properties are inheritable e.g. `font-family` or `color`. Those of them that aren't crossed are actually inherited by your inspected element.

P.S. A list of all inheritable properties: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612302/which-css-properties-are-inherited).

Comment: Can you give an example? I bet your answer is technically correct, but I still find it hard to understand, because I'm not as deeply in it as you are.

Comment: "respective ancestor element in the DOM tree" is hard to read. Show the smallest example possible: the simplest doc, and a tag that doesn't inherit, I guess. Or not, as you choose.

Comment: "In this case, the 'body' tag cannot inherit the 'margin' tag, because XYZ." Is that right? If so, what's the xyz? That would be an example.

Comment: These are exactly the sentences that should be in the answer. "In this case, you are inspecting a tag that is inside a body tag. The tag you are inspecting (not shown) cannot inherit the dimmed properties of margin and background-color."

Comment: It's not just CSS inheritance (which I understand at a high level, but not all the details), but the chrome interface, which I'm not incredibly familiar with. That's literally the question, what is the chrome interface saying.

Comment: Ah, then I guess there were two questions here. The other one was about the meaning of "Inherited from body" section.

Comment: Ha ha, I literally did not see that text until you just mentioned it! The UI has so much I didn't notice it.